# Wild card in c# string

Tags: c#

I want some way to express a wildcard symbol in C# this is the code i want to use the wild card in it's used to remove the tags from an xml code I already have

```
    public static String readfromnode(XNode x)
    {
        String before;
        before = x.ToString();
        before.Replace("<"the wild card should be here">", null);
        return before;
    }
```

I already tried using many symbols and associate them with `@` but nothing is working well.

for example the in put is

`**<head>
      <title>Benchmark 1</title>
    </head>**`

and the output is

**Benchmark 1**

Comment: Why do you want to do this with strings? An `XNode` probably represents the XML element and its contents in a structured way, so maybe you shouldn't throw away that with a `.ToString()` call?

Comment: You should post the XML and *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Even if the replace worked as you wanted, you're not assigning the result.

Comment: The key point of getting a correct answer is to ask a good question. what is your input and expected output? Where is your code related to `removing the xml tags`? I only see some string manipulations which are also incorrect.

Comment: first the xnode cant give me it's vaulue so i have to transform it into a string while the input is the xnode which already has the xml code and there is no specific xml im trying to parse in general when you remove the tags from the xml you have the text or value and thats what im trying to do but if you insist on an example i will show you one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "wildcard" solution using `String.Replace()`. Your best bet is to use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)-class, this is the exact kind of situation that regular expressions are intended for.

Whipped up a quick sample of how this could be done.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myString = "This is some <text with> some missplaced <tags in them> and we want to remove everything <between those tags>";
    myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(myString);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Now why was this downvoted? Please leave a comment on why you downvote an answer when you do.

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off using a regular expression:

```
public static string ReadFromNode(XNode node)
{
    string before = node.ToString();

    string after = Regex.Replace(before, @"<\w+>", string.Empty);

    return after;
}
```

The pattern `<\w+>` in this case means a `<` followed by one or more word characters followed by `>`. You can use a more complex pattern depending on your requirements.

Comment: While this is correct according to the question title, I would argue that one probably should not do this when parsing XML. +1 since the OP didn't include more details to help answer the question better.

Comment: "trevor pilley" it didn't work i tried this solution but the xml remained the same after applying the regex code so sorry but thanks to the help anyway :)

Comment: @user1806454 - can you post an example of what value is in the XNode?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this [Wildcard to regexes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11556/Converting-Wildcards-to-Regexes).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You could alternatively extract the tag as a substring and use Replace with the string you obtain.

Pseudo-code:

Find occurance of "<" then of ">" and extract the string between the tags to replace or directly extract the text from before and after the tag essentially removing it.

perhaps there is also a way to do this with Regular Expressions also.

Comment: i dont think it's going to work because there is too many tags and the extraction is going to be a pain in the ass thats why im looking for a wild card expression like * when your searching in a database